# Filtering Entity Framework Data Across Multiple Scalars?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, enums

Im trying to filter some data using EF in VB.NET.

I have Enums defined in my application, and depending on a combination of properties in EF, a status will apply. I would like to be able to filter by these Enum status.

An example would be:

```
Public Enum ConsultStatus
    Upcoming = 0
    Kept
    NoShow
    Cancelled
    Deleted
    Rescheduled
End Enum
```

And then for example:

```
IF apt.date >= date.today AND apt.isdeleted = "N" and apt.iscancelled = "N"
```

This would produce a ConsultStatus of Upcoming

My questions more specifically is that I would like to be able to bind to say a list view, and pass just in a status, such as filter = ConsultStatus.Upcoming

Is there an easier way then having to create a select/case for each Enum and how it is determined?

Comment: Tip: use ANDALSO, this will stop evaluation of the condition after the first condition that fails. Using AND will cause all conditions to be evaluated. For instance: `If x>0 AND 4/x<1` can still throw a `DivisionByZeroException`. Using ANDALSO this cannot happen.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your problem is. Perhaps you should provide some more code. You can always implement a `ReadOnly` property on the entity that encapsulates the logic you have shown. Filtering on this property should always be done in code, before presenting a collection of entities to the user interface.